# How to find out in Cisco JTAPI if a phone call is connected?

Tags: events, jtapi, cisco-jtapi

I'm trying to find out how to know if a call is connected, meaning the call was answered and the talking started.
I have the issue where the call is connected immediately after dialing, there is no ringback at all, and I was not able to figure out how to find out if the call is connected in this scenario. How can I find out from the events or any connection objects are whatever that the call is connected?

Below the events I get. 1044 is the calling number, 9106 the number of the application that is called, which immediately answers the call, so there is no ringback, and calls the agent with the number 1056.

```
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:05:307
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlConnDialingEv received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603678)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control ConnectionCiscoConnection hashCode(event): 24546998
ConnectionID(event): 26165083
CallControlCause(event): 110
CalledAddress(event): null
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): SEPCCD539D74CF7
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): null
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): null
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): SEPCCD539D74CF7
Address(Connection): 1044
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:05:310
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlTermConnTalkingEv SEPCCD539D74CF7 received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603678)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control Terminal ConnectionTerminalConnection hashCode(event): 21444301
CallControlCause(event): 110
CalledAddress(event): null
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): SEPCCD539D74CF7
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 9106
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 9106
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): SEPCCD539D74CF7
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:05:311
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlConnEstablishedEv received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603678)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control ConnectionCiscoConnection hashCode(event): 24546998
ConnectionID(event): 26165083
CallControlCause(event): 100
CalledAddress(event): 9106
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): SEPCCD539D74CF7
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 9106
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 9106
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): SEPCCD539D74CF7
Address(Connection): 1044
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:05:316
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlConnNetworkReachedEv received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603678)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control ConnectionCiscoConnection hashCode(event): 28047486
ConnectionID(event): 0
CallControlCause(event): -1
CalledAddress(event): 9106
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): SEPCCD539D74CF7
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 9106
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 9106
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): SEPCCD539D74CF7
Address(Connection): 9106
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:05:319
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlConnNetworkAlertingEv received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603678)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control ConnectionCiscoConnection hashCode(event): 28047486
ConnectionID(event): 0
CallControlCause(event): 100
CalledAddress(event): 9106
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): SEPCCD539D74CF7
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 9106
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 9106
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): SEPCCD539D74CF7
Address(Connection): 9106
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:05:482
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlConnEstablishedEv received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603678)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control ConnectionCiscoConnection hashCode(event): 28047486
ConnectionID(event): 0
CallControlCause(event): 100
CalledAddress(event): 9106
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): SEPCCD539D74CF7
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 9106
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 9106
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): SEPCCD539D74CF7
Address(Connection): 9106
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:08:409
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlConnOfferedEv received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603679)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control ConnectionCiscoConnection hashCode(event): 16848708
ConnectionID(event): 26165086
CallControlCause(event): 110
CalledAddress(event): 1056
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): Callisto_SIP_Tr
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 1056
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 1056
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): Callisto_SIP_Tr
Address(Connection): 1056
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:08:410
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlConnEstablishedEv received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603679)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control ConnectionCiscoConnection hashCode(event): 18484547
ConnectionID(event): 0
CallControlCause(event): 110
CalledAddress(event): 1056
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): Callisto_SIP_Tr
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 1056
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 1056
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): Callisto_SIP_Tr
Address(Connection): 1044
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:08:593
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlConnAlertingEv received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603679)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control ConnectionCiscoConnection hashCode(event): 16848708
ConnectionID(event): 26165086
CallControlCause(event): 100
CalledAddress(event): 1056
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): Callisto_SIP_Tr
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 1056
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 1056
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): Callisto_SIP_Tr
Address(Connection): 1056
-----------------------------------------------------------
---- 2015.08.17 11:34:08:595
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------
CallCtlTermConnRingingEvImpl SEPD824BDBA6DA7 received for call: (P2-CTIUser) GCID=(1,10603679)->ACTIVE
CiscoConnection Control Terminal ConnectionTerminalConnection hashCode(event): 2788310
CallControlCause(event): 100
CalledAddress(event): 1056
CallingAddress(event): 1044
CallingTerminal(event): Callisto_SIP_Tr
LastRedirectedAddress(event): null
CurrentCalledAddress(call): 1056
CurrentCallingAddress(call): 1044
IsCiscoConferenceCall(call): false
CalledAddress(call): 1056
CallingAddress(call): 1044
CallingTerminal(call): Callisto_SIP_Tr
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have found the solution to this issue myself in: [link]http://devrealm.org/2009/05/22/jtapi-hands-on-part-ii/
Get the connections of the call, if both connections are in state connected, the call is connected.

Comment: Though I've found a solution for this issue, I wonder, is there any better solution? Can I be sure my approach will work 100% correctly all the time?

Comment: Further tests have revealed that it can happen sometimes that I get only 1 connection object, where the condition is not true that 2 connections are in state connected. Any recommendations on how to handle this issue?